# How would i convert a String object to a UTF8CHAR pointer?

Tags: c++, function

Im integrating a new system, and the old system had a char* in a method.  Now there is a UTF8CHAR * instead.

I have a string object:

```
string data("test set");
```

and wanted to pass it into the function:

```
my_method(UTF8CHAR* text, ENUM extra, newStruct &item);
```

What my first attempt was:

```
newStruct param("hi", 0,0);
my_method(data.c_str(), extra::OPEN,param);
```

I dont get an ERROR, but instead a EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: There very little reason to assume that it has anything to do with the string.  Ask for help from whomever programmed that "new system".

Comment: I wasnt sure if there was a conversion issue with char* to Utf8Char*, i guess the answer to that is a no?  They auto convert into each other?

Comment: What is the type of UTF8CHAR ? char* ?
Your main problem here is that "data.c_str()" return a const value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `string` and a `char` array each contains a sequence of bytes. It depends on the library in question, but common sense indicates that a `UTF8CHAR` array is a sequence of bytes as well, with the added understanding that certain byte combinations describe certain unicode codepoints, and certain other byte combinations are illegal. So every utf8 char array is a char array, but not neccessarily the other way round. As the distinction is not a thing the compiler can check, except for ensuring proper data type handling, passing a char pointer should work. If it does not, perhaps something else went wrong, which we cannot decide from the code you posted.